# React - Select multiple checkboxes holding Shift key

Tags: reactjs, checkboxlist, shift

I have a list of checkboxes in my React App. When I hold Shift key and click one - the others between current and the nearest checked one should become selected.

For now I'm tring to do somethimg like this:

```
<input onChange={(e)=>this.handleCheckbox(e)} value={id} checked={this.state.selected.IndexOf(id) > -1} type="checkbox" />

handleCheckbox(e){
  if(e.shiftKey){
    console.log("shiftKey is hold")
  }
  //here goes some logic to save checkboxes in the state
}
```

But the condition `if(e.shiftKey)` is never executed.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You must use the `onKeyDown` event to capture keyboard changes. This will probably make you event handler a little more complex

Answer (score 6):

For future visitors:

To check if the Shift key is pressed, check the `e.nativeEvent.shiftKey` in the click event.

You still have to implement the logic for actually checking the boxes. If you need help with that, let me know.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`onChange` is trigged after you let the key up. You should use the `onKeyDown` event.